# Add Google Analytics tracking to a link

Tags: php

@Philip gave us this code snippet for adding to a link, to hook up with Google Analytics tracking.

```
onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Event Name', 'click', 'Button title/name']);"
```

Our actual code for outputted ads ( on our site , self served ads ) is yanked in using php and mysql. But the output of the ad is as follow.

```
 echo "<a href=\"" . $url . "\"><img src=\"" . $row['Image'] . "\" alt=\"" . $row['Caption'] . "\" title=\"" . $row['Caption'] . "\" /></a>";
```

How would I combine both code snippets above, so that I can add the onclick event tracking to the secondary snippet.

Cheers

---

Essentially at the moment we track in our own db clicks and impressions. We would like to obviously represent as much data about the ad itself ( not the page ) using some form of analytics.

The id for an ad is displayed as such

```
$url = "http://www.ourdomain.com/adserver.php?Clicked=" . $row['ID'];
```

So seemingly into the GA onclick( we would need to parse the same ID ) if thats correct. Im going round in circles here.

Answer (score 2):

You could try:

```
<?php
echo sprintf('<a href="%s" onclick="gaq.push([\'_trackEvent\', '
            .'\'Event Name\', \'click\', \'%s\']);"><img src="%s" '
            .'alt="%s" title="%s" /></a>',
             htmlspecialchars($url),
             htmlspecialchars($row['Caption']),
             $row['Image'],
             htmlspecialchars($row['Caption']),
             htmlspecialchars($row['Caption']));
```

Hope you don't mind I used [sprintf](http://php.net/sprintf) to make it a little easier to read, and also escaped certain values with [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) in case they contain special characters.  I added the caption to the `Event Name` parameter in gaq.push, but didn't do anything for the event name.